# How to show parameters of linear Fit in plot

Tags: plotting, fitting, legending

I am trying to do some analysis in experimental data, my code is as follows

```
m = 0.02; V = 20; Ci = 
 List[30, 50, 100, 200]; Cd = {3.5, 6.85, 16.5, 56.85}; Pb = {4.5, 
  7.95, 17.41, 38.59}; Zn = {4.3, 9.6, 22.3, 49.7}; Cr = {11.1, 22.2, 
  66.7, 148.1}; Ni = {3.0, 6.1, 15.2, 43.9}; 
qe[x_] := V/m (Ci - x); 
Langy[x_] := x/qe[x] (*Langmuir's s Y-axis*)

Langplot[x_] := 
 Transpose[{x, Langy[x]}](*Langmuir data, ready to plot*)

Langmuir[x_] := 
 LinearModelFit[Langplot[x], z, 
  z](*Linear fit of Langmuir data*)
lCd = Langmuir[Cd]; lPb = 
 Langmuir[Pb]; lZn = Langmuir[Zn]; lCr = Langmuir[Cr]; lNi = 
 Langmuir[Ni]; Show[
 ListPlot[{Langplot[Cd], Langplot[Pb], Langplot[Zn], Langplot[Ni]}], 
 Plot[{lCd[z], lPb[z], lZn[z], lNi[z]}, {z, 0, 60}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Cd", "Pb", "Zn", "Ni"}, PlotStyle -> Dashed], 
 PlotLabel -> "Langmuir Fit"]
```

Which gave the result I wanted 
[image]

Is there a way I can get the slopes of the linear fit and the $R^2$ parameters in my plot legends?

**Note:** My lists (Ci, Cd, Pb, etc) are much bigger, I just reduced their size here for simplicity.

Comment: Not automatically, at least that I know of. You could construct the legends manually or add text as an `Epilog` to your plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a little more work is necessary to display the parameters you want for your Langmuir isotherms. This relies on the fact that the `FittedModel[]` object produced by `LinearModelFit[]` can also be used to extract the fitted parameters of the line (the `"BestFitParameters"` property) and the coefficient of determination $R^2$ (the `"RSquared"` property).

To keep things convenient and tidy, I will bundle up the various computed parameters in an association:

```
syms = {"Cd", "Pb", "Zn", "Cr", "Ni"};

slopeassoc = AssociationThread[syms,
                       Through[{lCd, lPb, lZn, lCr, lNi}["BestFitParameters"]][[All, 2]]];

r2assoc = AssociationThread[syms, Through[{lCd, lPb, lZn, lCr, lNi}["RSquared"]]];
```

From there, we can write a little function to do the legend formatting:

```
st = "`sym` (slope = `m`, \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"R\", \"2\"]\) = `r2`)";
makeLegend[s_] := TemplateApply[st,
   <|"sym" -> s, "m" -> ToString[ScientificForm[Lookup[slopeassoc, s], 6], StandardForm],
     "r2" -> Lookup[r2assoc, s]|>]
```

Then, we only need to apply this to your legends, like so:

```
Show[ListPlot[{Langplot[Cd], Langplot[Pb], Langplot[Zn], Langplot[Ni]}], 
     Plot[{lCd[z], lPb[z], lZn[z], lNi[z]}, {z, 0, 60}, PlotLabel -> "Langmuir Fit", 
          PlotLegends -> Evaluate[makeLegend /@ {"Cd", "Pb", "Zn", "Ni"}], 
          PlotStyle -> Dashed]]
```

[image: Langmuir isotherms]